B&W Sci-fi movie; something glowing in the ground(UFO?); people try to walk over it but they die
B&W Sci-fi movie; something glowing in the ground(UFO?); people try to walk over it but they die.
This from my childhood and I've never been able to place the movie but this one scene has always been stuck in my head.

Your details remind me of the 1956 movie "X the Unknown", about a radiation-seeking blob monster from deep within the earth. The thing emits extremely hard radiation that fries people in its vicinity, and at the end the monster glows from the excess energy it's absorbed.
